# Wrong hash in C++ implementation of SHA-1

Tags: c++, sha1

I'm trying to write an implementation of SHA-1 in C++. For some reason I'm getting a different output than I'm expecting.

Input `test` should result in `a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3`.

Instead I'm getting the output `e58f4aa9a69bb1cc73084c1c87e991d3d3bb2f98`.

I have the following function

```
void sha1(const uint8_t *org_msg, size_t org_len, uint8_t *digest)
```

Which I call like

```
// msg = original input
// org_len = original length of input
// output = uint8_t output[20];
sha1((uint8_t *)msg.c_str(), org_len, output);
```

I have these five variables at the end of the compression function (which are correct as you can see [here](http://www.metamorphosite.com/show-steps?subject=6&topic=17&input=test) at the botom of the page)

```
h0 = 10101001010010101000111111100101
h1 = 11001100101100011001101110100110
h2 = 00011100010011000000100001110011
h3 = 11010011100100011110100110000111
h4 = 10011000001011111011101111010011
```

The variables are all of type `uint32_t`. Now I want to convert them to `uint8_t` which I have the following function for:

```
void to_bytes(uint32_t val, uint8_t *bytes) {
    bytes[0] = (uint8_t)val;
    bytes[1] = (uint8_t)(val >> 8);
    bytes[2] = (uint8_t)(val >> 16);
    bytes[3] = (uint8_t)(val >> 24);
}
```

And I call it like

```
to_bytes(h0, digest);
to_bytes(h1, digest + 4);
to_bytes(h2, digest + 8);
to_bytes(h3, digest + 12);
to_bytes(h4, digest + 16);
```

And then finally output it like so:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    printf("%2.2x", output[i]);
}
```

Which results in `e58f4aa9a69bb1cc73084c1c87e991d3d3bb2f98`.

Comment: `to_bytes` produces reversed output. `bytes[0]` will get the last 8 bits of the input, while you want the first 8 bits.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Stupid of me for not seeing it. You answer it and I'll tick it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`to_bytes` produces reversed output. `bytes[0]` will get the last 8 bits of the input, while you want the first 8 bits.